# Windows credential for LAN network access overwritten by HomeGroupUser$

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, credentials-manager

I'm trying to access a shared folder on a Windows 7 machine on my home network. I'm using another Windows 7 machine in order to access the first one.

Whenever I logout and login to my account, Windows replaces the OTHER_MACHINE\USERNAME credential by OTHER_MACHINE\HomeGroupUser$ , overwriting the old credentials I typed it.

In order to type in the correct credentials, I've used Windows Credential Manger, then I removed the HomeGroupUser$ credential, and added a Windows Credential with the correct OTHER_MACHINE\USERNAME details. In addition to all these steps, I already have the correct credentials typed under Generic Credentials, with Enterprise persistence. Unfortunately, after logging out and logging in, the correct Windows Credentials are overwritten with HomeGroupUser$ , and my machine refuses to properly connect to the other machine.

How can this be solved?

Thanks,

Shlomi

Answer (score 1):

Change the default selection from “Allow Windows to Manage HomeGroup Connections” to “Use User Accounts and Passwords to Connect to Other Computers”.

This settings could be found on the bottom of Advanced Sharing Settings (Control panel / Network and Internet / Network and Sharing Center / Advanced Sharing Settings)

Comment: Thanks. I thought of it too. The problem is that you basically trust any Windows machine which isn't blocked from connecting to your computer...

Comment: I don't think so, only machine which forms part of a home network, it means should know the home network password.
Anyway I think the solution to keep the OTHER_MACHINE\USERNAME in your credential is to change the default selection from “Allow Windows to Manage HomeGroup Connections” to “Use User Accounts and Passwords to Connect to Other Computers”. 
This settings could be found on the bottom of Advanced Sharing Settings  (Control panel / Network and Internet / Network and Sharing Center / Advanced Sharing Settings)

I hope this helps